# gulp-template (lodash) falls over with javascript templating

Tags: gulp, lodash

I am running a gulp script with gulp-template to inject values into my javascript files.

e.g.

```
angular
    .module("<%= module %>", [
        "ngRoute",
        "ui.bootstrap",
        "ui.select"
    ]);
```

This works fine for all the files except if I have javascript templating in the file

e.g.

```
    function controller() {
        var vm = this;

        vm.getMessage = getMessage;

        //------------------------------------------

        function getMessage() {
            if (!vm.validator)
                return "";

            var message = vm.validator.getMessage(vm.property);

            if (message === "")
                return "";

            return ` *${message}`;
        }
    }
```

I then get the following error

```
events.js:167
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
ReferenceError: message is not defined
    at eval (lodash.templateSources[10]:9:10)
    at DestroyableTransform._transform (C:\andre\sourcecode\pmslogic\buildassets\node_modules\gulp-template\index.js:23:41)
    at DestroyableTransform.Transform._read (C:\andre\sourcecode\pmslogic\buildassets\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stre
am\lib\_stream_transform.js:184:10)
    at DestroyableTransform.Transform._write (C:\andre\sourcecode\pmslogic\buildassets\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-str
eam\lib\_stream_transform.js:172:83)
    at doWrite ([my path]node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:42
8:64)
    at writeOrBuffer ([my path]node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable
.js:417:5)
    at DestroyableTransform.Writable.write ([my path]node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-strea
m\lib\_stream_writable.js:334:11)
    at write ([my path]node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:623:
24)
    at flow ([my path]node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:632:7
)
    at DestroyableTransform.pipeOnReadable ([my path]node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\readable-strea
m\lib\_stream_readable.js:664:5)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at DestroyableTransform.onerror ([my path]node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_
stream_readable.js:558:12)
    at DestroyableTransform.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at DestroyableTransform._transform ([my path]node_modules\gulp-template\index.js:26:9)
    at DestroyableTransform.Transform._read ([my path]node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stre
am\lib\_stream_transform.js:184:10)
    [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
    at flow ([my path]node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:632:7
)
```

I suspect I can solve this by passing lodash template parameters into the gulp-template call, but am stumped as to what these are.

```
var gulp = require("gulp");
var concat = require("gulp-concat");
var template = require('gulp-template');

...

var cfg = ????

return gulp
    .src(src)
    .pipe(template({ module: "test-module-name" }, cfg))
    .pipe(concat(`${module}.js`))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(dest));
};
```